# dayJS date function to PHP Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon, dayjs

I have the following date processing in dayjs which I am trying to replicate in PHP but failing. I expect both to return Monday 27 July 2020.  Can someone help?

**JS - returns Monday 27 July 2020**

```
var firstOfMonth = dayjs('2020-08-01'),
    weekOneStart = firstOfMonth.clone().day(1); // Monday

console.log(weekOneStart);
```

**PHP - returns Monday 3 August 2020**

```
$d = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-08-01');
echo $d->firstOfMonth(1);
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the first Sunday/Monday of the month, or are you trying to get the first Sunday/Monday of the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions are different, as the JS function gets the first Monday of the week, while the Carbon function gets the first Monday of the month. You can see this in the Carbon code for firstOfMonth:

```
public function firstOfMonth($dayOfWeek = null)
{
    $this->startOfDay();

    if ($dayOfWeek === null) {
        return $this->day(1);
    }

    return $this->modify('first '.static::$days[$dayOfWeek].' of '.$this->format('F').' '.$this->year);
}
```

If you want to get the first day of the week, then you need to use `$d->startOfWeek();`

```
$d = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-08-01');
$d->startOfWeek();
// object(Carbon\Carbon)(
//   'date' => '2020-07-27 00:00:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 3,
//   'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
// )
```

Comment: I perhaps should have been more specific but yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. This works perfectly.  Thank you for your help